# Calling variables into in-app email with

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, email, nsuserdefaults

Hey everyone, what I'm trying to do is grab variables from textfields on my interface and use them in a email triggerd by a button directly beneath those buttons. I followed a tutorial to show me how to do this, formatting using a .html file and i've not been able to actually substitute those placeholders in the file! If someone could please tell me what I'm doing wrong, or what would work that would be appreciated!

Here is the code from the implementation file in the method of clicking the email button

```
- (IBAction)email:(id)sender {
    MFMailComposeViewController *compose = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    compose.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [compose setSubject:@"Float Plan for my Boat Trip"];
    [compose setCcRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"towboat911@gmail.com"]];

    NSUserDefaults *person = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [person setObject:personField.text forKey:@"person"];

    NSUserDefaults *pob = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [pob setObject:pobField.text forKey:@"pob"];

    NSUserDefaults *phone = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [phone setObject:phoneField.text forKey:@"phone"];

    NSUserDefaults *medical = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [medical setObject:medicalField.text forKey:@"medical"];

    NSUserDefaults *depart = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [depart setObject:departField.text forKey:@"depart"];

    NSUserDefaults *left = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [left setObject:leftField.text forKey:@"left"];

    NSUserDefaults *arrive = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [arrive setObject:arriveField.text forKey:@"arrive"];

    NSUserDefaults *destination = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [destination setObject:destinationField.text forKey:@"destination"];


    NSString *emailFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email_en_US.html"];
    NSString *emailFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: emailFileName];
    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:emailFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PERSON//" withString:@"person"];
    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PERSONSIGN//" withString:@"person"];
    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//POB//" withString:@"pob"];
    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PHONE//" withString:@"phone"];
    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//MEDICAL//" withString:@"medical"];
    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//DEPART//" withString:@"depart"];
    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//LEFT//" withString:@"left"];
    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//ARRIVAL//" withString:@"arrive"];
    body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//DESTINATION//" withString:@"destination"];

    NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:body];
    [compose setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    compose.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    [self presentModalViewController:compose animated:YES];
    [compose release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines that replace strings in body don't look right.  For example, this:

```
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PERSON//" 
           withString:@"person"];
```

should probably be this:

```
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PERSON//" 
           withString:personField.text];
```

Same goes for the rest of the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString lines.

Additionally, you don't need to create a separate reference to NSUserDefaults for each key you want to save.  So instead of declaring `NSUserDefaults *person`, `NSUserDefaults *pob`, etc., just declare one reference like `NSUserDefaults *defaults` and use that on all the setObject calls.